# Best way to store large data in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, filepath

I have a news website created with ASP.NET MVC.

Below is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[News] (
[NewsID]         INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[InstitutionID]  INT            NOT NULL,
[Title]          NVARCHAR (450) NOT NULL,
[NewsDate]       DATETIME       NOT NULL,
[Description]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[path]           NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[PostedBy]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[ContactPhone]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[ContactEmail]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[NewsExpiryDate] DATETIME       NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.News] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([NewsID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.News_dbo.state_InstitutionID] FOREIGN KEY ([InstitutionID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[state] ([InstitutionID]) ON DELETE CASCADE );
```

I noticed that my database has increased to 8GB, and it is getting slower to load a page.

I am thinking of storing the news in a file and then saving the path in database.

Is there anyway I can convert the form value representing "[Description]" into a file and then store the path to my database?

Comment: I think I would spend some time learning what takes up the space For instance, do you really need all those `NVARCHAR(MAX)` columns to be that large? I can't imagine why you would need phone numbers and emails to be that large. And you don't appear to be storing any binary data. Finally, are you sure this is the _data_ size and does not include the _log_ size?

Comment: `"Slower to load the page"...` I'd first measure/profile the code and SQL queries that are used to load the page and identify what is the bottleneck. The size of the database doesn't really matter as long as you don't scan through all 8GB to show one page.

Comment: The size of the database is rarely the performance bottleneck.  Especially given your statement that it's getting slower as it grows.  As Vladimir said, profile it.  Then you'll know exactly what the issue is.  I'd lay hard cold cash on it being related to bad queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly you can store files locally and then 'link' to them in the database. But that approach is probably the wrong one if your application and database are not on the same server (the database server should be optimized for file storage, and that's where files should go). First, You lose all querying and indexing possibilities if you store your `Description` field off-db.  Second, the database server "should" be powerful enough for this task. You should look into tuning the database engine and server.

Let's assume you've done all that. You need to make sure your application (the thing connecting to the db) can write and read these files. You probably need to set up a top-level directory that has plenty of space. You should pay attention to permissions/security -- who can read/write these files. Finally, you need a scheme of storing files and creating these files. A typical scheme is to convert the description to a hash (md5 would be OK here, sha256 would be best) and use the hash as the filename. You chop of the filename so that it contains 2 or 3 levels of directories (large directories often slow some systems down): So `ab2442vc25` becomes `a/b2/442vc25`. Store your description there and store the path name in `Description_path`. Keep `Description` null in those cases.

But I'm skeptical this will actually help.

Comment: Thanks Otheus, I really understand all that. What I don't actually get clearly here is how I can extract the content of my html form field (Description) and save it in a seperate file while storing the path to db.

Comment: "extract the content of my html form field" -- that's a completely different question. "and save it in a separate file while storing the path to the db" that is indeed ANOTHER question. I answered part of it in the 2nd half of my answer, above.

Answer (score 0):

As [John Saunders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76337/john-saunders) stated in the comments, you misuse `nvarchar(max)`. 
If the `Title` can be stored in 450 chars, the `ContactPhone` can certainly be stored in less then 20. the `PostedBy` and `Email` also can be truncated to a more appropriate size, and I'm guessing the `path` also should not be over a 100 chars at most.
Also, If possible, I would probably move the `PostedBy`, `ContactPhone` and `ContactEmail` to a new table (I would probably call it  `NewsAuthors`) and replace them in the News table by a foreign key to this table. This have the potential to save you a lot of storage space.

As to performance, storage size is usually not the problem, as [NotMe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2424/notme) suggested in the comments.
You can probably improve performance dramatically by using proper queries  and indexes on your database.

A good place to start is running your most frequent queries directly on SSMS and view the execution plan. sql server may suggest creating indexes. if it does, create them.

Comment: Thanks @zohar_peled, I really understand all that. What I don't actually get clearly here is how I can extract the content of my html form field (Description) and save it in a seperate file while storing the path to db.